# redshift equivalent of TEXT data type

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

What's the best data type to use for a column in a redshift table that will hold a very long string (can be up to 50KB)?

TEXT is replaced by `varchar(256)` by default. For now I used `varchar(65535)`, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do that...

Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful to know why you're trying to jam article-sized text into columns...

Comment: @SerbanTanasa - It's a very big table  - around 100G that I need to be able to query. One of the fields is free text and can be very long. If you can suggest a better way to do that I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Have you considered a Hadoop or NoSQL solution?

Answer (score 32):

**Text Data Type in Redshift:**

For Redshift Text Data Type you can use `varchar(max)` or `varchar(65535)`

That is the maximum length of a text data type field in Redshift.

Comment: Nevermind, found it in the answer below: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html

Comment: just curious, if it's a numerical limit, why 65535 and not 65536?

Answer (score 5):

`VARCHAR`, `CHARACTER VARYING` and `NVARCHAR` can have a length of up to 65k.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html

Comment: yes, I saw these docs, see my edit. Still not sure that's the best way to store this data.

Comment: I have not found any other types that can hold more data. I don't think there are any types better suited for this. Although there might be a better way (other DBMS or a filesystem?) than to store the whole text inside one column.

Comment: this would mean I suppose that every record in the table is allocated 65k regardless of the actual length of the text..

Comment: No, it does not. Read the part about varchar in the link above: > Use a VARCHAR or CHARACTER VARYING column to store variable-length strings with a fixed limit. These strings are not padded with blanks, so a VARCHAR(120) column consists of a maximum of 120 single-byte characters, 60 two-byte characters, 40 three-byte characters, or 30 four-byte characters.

Comment: It seems to be "4 bytes + total bytes for characters" according to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99361/storage-size-for-varchar-length-in-redshift

Comment: However, you should be cautious of having too large columns. Amazon themeselves recommend keeping it as small as possible, because when doing complex queries the data will not be compressed: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-smallest-column-size.html